# Underscore.js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'template' of null

Tags: underscore.js, requirejs

```js
require.config({
     paths: {
         jquery: 'libs/jquery',
         underscore: 'libs/underscore',
    }
});
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    ], function($,_){
        var test = _.template("hello: <%= name %>",{name:"warren"});

});
```

Given the above code using requirejs to load jquery and underscore, why am I getting this error...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'template' of null
```

All JS seems to be loading... The error points to the _.template line.  This is driving me crazy...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure you've bundled the underscore library to be usable with requireJS ?

When you write :

```js
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
  ], function($,_){
      var test = _.template("hello: <%= name %>",{name:"warren"});

});
```

The '_' variable (second argument of the callback function) is assigned with the export of the underscore library (second dependency specified).

I guess you used the original version of underscore, which is not package for requireJS.
In your underscore.js file, add the following line at the begining:

```js
define(function () {
```

and this line at the end:

```js
return _;});
```

Thus, the export are well configured.

Another possible solution is to use the global '_' variable: all you need to do is to remove the second argument of your callback.

```js
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
  ], function(){
      var test = _.template("hello: <%= name %>",{name:"warren"});

});
```

From there, your browser will use the '_' global variable, which is defined in underscore, and which is set when the callback is called.

Same behaviour is expected with jQuery.

Comment: Thanks, this worked!  I ended up just adding to the underscore file as you mentioned.